# How to effect other div properties when a different div is hovered on?

Tags: html, css, hover

this is my 1st post over here, ill try to be as clear as possible and hope I'm following the site's rules.

Not so long ago I started to play a little bit with some HTML/CSS, I got pretty good at it but not enough I guess and I hope to get some help over here.

I'm trying to build a navigation menu and one of it's features I would like it to have is when I hover over the ***"Account"*** button it should split the menu in the middle and show a new section where the user can log-in into his or hers account.

This is what I got so far and for some reason I cant make the effect when hovering over the ***"Account"*** `div` but it doe's work when I apply the hover effect on the entire top `div` (where the "Account `div` is a part of). tried all "linking" methods suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered) and still nothing... Also last thing: When i did `overflow: hidden;` on the .middle `div` it added a space between the top and bottom `divs`.

I would highly appreciate any help and if it's possible to leave it at the CSS level (without any jQuery or any other coding)

Thanks in advance,
Tony.

```css
.container {
  width: 560px;
  height: auto;
}

.top {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.top-L {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.top-R {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}

.middle {
  height: 0px;
  width: 560px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: .4s ease;
}

.bottom {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.top:hover + .middle {
  height: 50px;
  transition: .4s ease;
}

.middle:hover {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body style="font-family: sans-serif; background-color: #ccc;">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="top-L">Other</div>
    <div class="top-R">Account</div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot get the effect for the button only with pure CSS, you need Javascript for that. The reason is that the login box is not a direct following sibling of the button, but of its parent.

Comment: @Gerard technically you could use position absolute maybe depending on the requirements.

Comment: @Tony, What if i do it with click instead of hover?

Comment: @Gerard I consulted with a developer friend and he told me the same about using Javascript, I really want to keep it in pure CSS so I'll probably go with the solution hunzaboy suggested.

Comment: @William what do you mean by `position: absolute` ?

Comment: @hunzaboy that will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

What you are looking for is not possible with your current structure. However, we can do it via `Click`, Instead of `Hover`. **With some changes :)**. It is not the perfect solution but should work in your situation.

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 560px;
  height: auto;
}

.top {
  /* height: 50px; */
  background-color: red;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}

.top-L label, .top-R label{
 padding: 20px;
}

.top-L {
  order: 1;
 padding: 20px;
}

.top-R {
  padding: 20px;
}

.middle {
  height: 0px;
  width: 560px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: .4s ease;
}

.bottom {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
.top:hover + .middle {
  /* height: 50px; */
  transition: .4s ease;
 

}
#account{
 display: none;
}
#account:checked + .middle{
 height: 50px;
 padding: 10px;
}

.middle:hover {
  /* height: 50px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="top-L">Other</div>
    <div class="top-R" ><label for="account">Account</label> </div>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="account"/>
  <div class="middle">
    <div>
   
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: * it should split the menu in the middle and show a new section where the user can log-in into his or hers account*

Answer (score 0):

If I am right this will help you,

```css
nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block
}
nav > ul > li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 105%;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.2s 1s;
}
nav > ul > li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav li {
  width: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Last</a></li>
    <li><a href="">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="">is</a></li>
    <li>
      Dropdown
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tony Mor made some correction on your existing css. I believe it's what you want.

```
.top-R {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

and

```
.middle div {
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that did helped with the gap :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)